# How to read a dictionary (.dic extension) file in client side?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there any possibility to read a dictionary (.dic extension) file in javascript or jquery?

Comment: Yes. That's about as detailed as it can get without any details about what you're trying to do.

Comment: @Schlaus I will have a dictionary file in local system or in a server location. how do we read that file content in javascript and store the read content in one variable.

Comment: Here's an MDN article about the subject: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_files_from_web_applications

Comment: @Schlaus I couldn't read the files based on the file URL by using this method. I can read the file only by browsing the file in this method.